# Symfony CSRF token invalid

Tags: symfony, doctrine-orm, twig, fosuserbundle

My project worked fine on my local computer. But once I uploaded it on an OVH server I faced some problems when I submit any form I have (such as registration of `FOSUserBundle` and also my own forms).

The problem is when I submit the form I have an invalid CSRF token.

I tried many solutions:

- I added `{{ form_rest(form) }}` to my twig files.
- I changed `csrf_protection` to `false` in `app/config/config.yml` and then the request was submited without any field from the form.

Note : I tried with symfony 2.4 and 2.3 but the problem persists.

My twig:

```
<form id="modifier_form" name="modifier_form" method="post" {{ form_enctype(form) }}>
    <div id="form_prenom">{{ form_row(form.prenom) }}</div>
    <div id="form_nom">{{ form_row(form.nom) }}</div>

    <div id="form_situation_pro">
        <label>Situation professionnelle</label>
        <select name="optone" 
                id="pays_select"
                onchange="setOptions(document.modifier_form.optone.options[document.modifier_form.optone.selectedIndex].value);">
                    <option value=" " selected="selected"> </option>
                    {% for a in pays  %}
                        <option value="{{ a.getId }}">{{ a.getName }}</option>
                    {% endfor %}
        </select>
    </div>
    <div id="form_situation_pro_sous">
        <label></label>
        <select name="opttwo" id="region_select">
            <option value=" " selected="selected"></option>
        </select>
    </div>

    {{ form_widget(form) }}
    {{ form_restt(form) }}
    <input type="submit" value="Enregistrer" />
```

My Controller

```
public function modifierAction(){
    $connecteduser =$this->getUser();
    $fich=$connecteduser->getFichsig();
    //si l'utulisateur a deja une fiche sinon il faut le remplire
    if(!$fich){
        $fich = new Fichsig;
        $connecteduser->setFichsig($fich);
    }

    $myuser=$this->getDoctrine()
        ->getManager()
        ->getRepository('TS\InscriptionBundle\Entity\User')->findByEmail($connecteduser->getEmail());

    $form = $this->createForm(new UserType($this->getDoctrine()->getManager()), $connecteduser);

    $request = $this->getRequest();
    if ($request->isMethod('POST')) {
        $form->bindRequest($request);
        if ($form->isValid()) {
            //get parametres
            ////
            $connecteduser->setFichsig($fich);
            $em = $this->getDoctrine()->getManager();
            $em->merge($connecteduser);
            $em->flush();
            return $this->redirect($this->generateUrl('ts_inscription_profil'));
        }
    }
    // On passe la méthode createView() du formulaire à la vue afin qu'elle puisse afficher le formulaire toute seule
    return $this->render('TSInscriptionBundle:Logged:modifier_logged_layout.html.twig', array(
        'form' => $form->createView(),
        'pays'=>$this->pays(),
        'region'=>$this->region(),

    ));
}
```

My config.yml

```
framework:
#esi:             ~
translator:      { fallback: "%locale%" }
secret:          "%secret%"
router:
    resource: "%kernel.root_dir%/config/routing.yml"
    strict_requirements: ~
form:            ~
csrf_protection: ~
validation:      { enable_annotations: true }
templating:
    engines: ['twig']
    #assets_version: SomeVersionScheme
default_locale:  "%locale%"
trusted_hosts:   ~
trusted_proxies: ~
session:
    # handler_id set to null will use default session handler from php.ini
    handler_id:  ~
fragments:       ~
http_method_override: true
```

Comment: can you post some PHP, twig and corresponding genrated HTML?

Answer (score 1):

You wrote

> {{ form_restt(form) }}

It should be like:

> {{ form_rest(form) }}

and also remove `{{ form_widget(form) }}`. It used to render part of the form. As you have already rendered a field **`form.prenom`**. form_rest will render the rest of the fields.

Happy Coding...

Comment: Sorry I made a mistake in copy for {{ form_restt(form) }}
I also removed {{ form_widget(form) }} but still nothing changed

Comment: Could you try to update your form type's **setDefaultOptions** function like [here](http://pastebin.com/ydLnPTee) and let me know the result

Comment: I already tried it and retried it again. The result is that the form is rendred with empty values and it updates my databases with empty values

Comment: So this disable the csrf validation! Now could you change the `$form->bindRequest($request);` to `$form->handleRequest($request);`

Comment: now when I submit, the form is reseted (the redirect don't work) with and without 'csrf_protection' => false

Comment: As per your code the page is suppose to redirect! But I didn't get what do you mean by reseted?

Comment: I mean all fields are empty after I submit the form like the action of reset button

Comment: I am now confused!! Let we break in steps. 1. What is your goal? 2.What is the problem?(is it CSRF validation? or Data Not Saving? or form getting resetting? all are different problem.) As I can only reply as per your feedback only, so its need to be clear to me. I am only looking at part of your code. So first need to find out, which part is the root of your problem(s)

Comment: The problem is that on local (dev and prod) everything works fine, but once we uploaded the project on a web hosting (OVH if you know it) no form woks even FOSUser ones ( registration, login, and forgot password reseting)

Comment: We are back to where we were :) **no form woks**. Working of form has several parts: 1.Rendering Form, 2. Handle submission, 3. validation. Your first guess was CSRF validation, which we have disabled(not solved), Now about rendering as you are able to submit the form, I am guessing it is rendering properly. Now about handle submission, if you can var_dump the request you can verify if its working or not. saving data is task of entity manager. if you can verify all three is working, then form is ok(without CSRF)

Answer (score 0):

you can simply let the twig render it for you using {{ form(form) }} once starting to use widget, rows and labels then you will have to use ***{{ form_start(form) }}*** and after the submit button and before the ***{{form_end(form) }}*** you should put ***{{ form_rest(form) }}***

I think you are missing the form_end and correct the form_rest as it has a spelling mistake

Answer (score -1):

Set the form end if you use symfony 2.3

```
{{ form_end(form, {'render_rest': false}) }}
```

Comment: I would like to remind you that it work fine on local( dev and prod mode).

Comment: @Yakiv Mospan , it's a twig code and not a java. it's {{ ... }}